# BlackBerry - Access to web service from real device

Tags: networking, blackberry, web-services

hi i have developed a application, that works fine on the simulator, now i want to test the application on the actual device.
my application tries to access web services over the internet. I mean to say, the application makes SOAP request to web services. Also i am accessing the web services using https
So in this case, do i need to first sign the application.
if not, then how do i go ahead, with deploying the application.

i tried deploying the application, using the blackberry desktop manager, the application got installed, but it is not making calls to web service.i mean to say, the application is not hitting the web service

Comment: You can find Browser at Blackberry Home Screen, browser app will have a name like "Browser" or "web2go" or smth like that

Comment: Tip: Use the JavaLoader.exe to load your app onto your device. Much faster. The command line would look something like:
%javaloader% -u load "BBApp.cod"

Answer (score 2):

Are you getting any error messages from the application?  If you need to sign any API's then you'll receive an error.

Use the Blackberry Browser to check if you can hit the webservice.  Sometimes there can be issues if your handset is on a BES or if the webservice is behind a firewall.

Check that you have connections or it will timeout.

Comment: where do i get the blackberry browser

Comment: Also i dont get any error , when i try to access web services

Comment: Are you successfully hitting the webservice?  Maybe the error is in the webservice?

Comment: no i am not able to hit the web service, thats the whole problem.
But the same application hits the web service using Nokia device.
The problem is in blackberry

Comment: same problem here, whats the solution?

Answer (score 1):

For https connection you can refer to foll. post :

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Connecting-your-BlackBerry-http-and-socket-connections-to-the/m-p/206242

Answer (score 0):

This issue has to do with some MDS servers having a low default for how large the requests they can pass through are:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/HTTP-413-Request-Entity-Too-Large/ta-p/445983

Still trying to sort out a good solution to this myself for a service that returns a large XML packet since it can't be reliably known whether a user's service has the default minimum or something higher.